# $\lim_{x \to 0}x^2 (a^{1/x} - a^{1/(x-1)}); a > 0$

Tags: calculus, limits

First post in this forum. This is from my first semester calculus course.... I'm completely lost.

$$\lim_{x \to 0}x^2 (a^{1/x} - a^{1/(x-1)}); a > 0$$

Any hints or steps would be cool

Thanks!

Comment: You missed a delimiter `$`. Is the exponent $1/(x-1)$ or $(1/x)-1$?

Comment: @player3236 its 1/(x-1).

Comment: @player3236 i need to learn this LaTex stuff.. thanks for helping out!

Comment: I see you already got the basics. Most people struggle with using curly brackets :)

Comment: As to your question, only $x^2a^{1/x}$ should pose an issue when taking the limit, so focus on that term.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As to $x \to \infty$ mentioned by @Z Ahmed, by the mean value theorem, there exists a $\theta_x$ between $\frac{1}{x}$ and $\frac{1}{x-1}$ such that

$$x^2 (a^{1/x} - a^{1/(x-1)}) = x^2 a^{\theta_x} \ln a \left(\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{x-1}\right) = -a^{\theta_x} \ln a\frac{x^2}{x(x-1)}. $$

Since $\theta_x \to 0$ as $x \to \infty$, then

$$\lim_{x \to \infty} x^2 (a^{1/x} - a^{1/(x-1)}) = -\ln a.$$

Comment: awesome, this was the solution I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**Note** the correct question would be when $x \to \infty$, to get a finte limit:
$$L=\lim_{x \to \infty}x^2 (a^{1/x} - a^{1/(x-1)}); a > 0$$
Let $x=1/t$, then
$$L=\lim_{t\to 0} \frac{a^t-a^{t/(1-t)}}{t^2} =\lim_{t\to 0} \frac{a^t-a^{t+t^2}}{t^2}=\lim_{t \to 0} -a^t \frac{a^{t^2}-1}{t^2}\\=\lim_{t \to 0} -a^{t} \frac{1+t^2 \ln a-1}{t^2}=-\ln a, a>0$$
In the above we have used binomial approximation $\frac{t}{1-t}\to t(1+t)$ and $a^z=1+z\ln a+...$ when $|t|$ and $|z|$ are very small.

Comment: $a^t-a^{t+t^2}=-a^t(a^{\frac{t^2}{1-t}}-1)\sim -a^t\frac{t^2}{1-t}$ as $t\to 0.$